# Ubuntu 18.04 - mouse pointer no longer 'sees' URL links

Tags: 18.04, mouse, mouse-pointer

I'm running Firefox 83 on Ubuntu 18.04. Since the FF 83 upgrade, my mouse pointer no longer does the 'transform' into a pointing finger when it floats over a link.

If I click on a link, I can briefly see the finger as the link launches.

So it's not the end of the world, but I'd like a solution.

And yes, when I gave the OK to the offered upgrade prompt, there may have been something else on there that I haven't (sorry) remembered.

Cheers

John M.

Comment: Firefox 83?   I'm not a *bionic* user, but I'd not expect it to be 83... `firefox | 93.0+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1   | bionic-security  | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x`

Comment: Right click on a link. Choose "Inspect". A new window appears. Somewhere in the right pane, there is a box called "Filter styles". Type in `cursor`. A rule should appear: something like `:any-link { cursor: pointer;}`. Does that happen?

Comment: Is that "Inspect Accessibility Properties" or "Inspect Element"?

Comment: OK, it's "inspect element'...

Comment: If I type 'cursor' into the filter styles entry field,  the field background goes red, which I think means 'not found'.

Comment: Interesting. What happens if you visit the user stylesheet at `resource://gre-resources/ua.css`?You ought to see a file that contains the CSS rule I mentioned on line 149 or thereabouts.

Comment: Like this:   *|*:any-link {
  cursor: pointer;
}

Comment: So the user stylesheet is in place, but it doesn't get loaded. Are any of the user agent files mentioned in that inspector pane? There should be links like `(useragent) html.css:109` (or `ua.css`, or `forms.css`). Again, `ua.css` contains the rule that turns your cursor in a pointing finger.

Comment: Most of the entries in the inspector pane begin with 'Inherited from', and I can't see anything about useragent or css.  BTW,  askUbuntu doesn't seem to like me posting repeated comments; asks me if I want to move the conversation to a chat.  Don't see why I should assume you'd be OK with that.

Comment: There's nothing I could add at this point - it seems like Firefox is not behaving as it should. The user stylesheets are there, but are ignored. You may have more luck asking the question on https://support.mozilla.org.

Comment: Hey Jos, thank you for your time.